VisionOS: How to implement drag and drop within a RealityKit attachment view?
I am trying to implement a drag-and-drop functionality of some UI elements in my VisionOS app. My UI is represented as an attachment view in the middle of a fully immersive RealityView. Basically I am dragging a data element represented by an Image in the UI to another location in the same attachment window, also represented by a Image.
My simplified code looks something like:
            Image("MyImage")
                .resizable()
                .onDrag {
                    return NSItemProvider(object: NSString())
                }
                .onDrop(of: [UTType.text], delegate: MyDropDelegateImplementation())
                .hoverEffect(.highlight)
                .hoverEffect { effect, isActive, proxy in
                    effect.scaleEffect(!isActive ? 1.0 : 1.1)
                }

Several things are not working here; notably,

hoverEffect { .. scaleEffect() } blocks the drag operation entirely, it simply does not start. When I comment that bit out, the drag starts. Note that hoverEffect(.highlight) does not prevent drag from starting. The effect is the same if I use .draggable / .dropDestination.
.onDrop() (or .dropDestination, if choose to use that) elements show no visual cue and do not react to dragging over them / ending the drag on them to cause the drop. No methods in the delegate get called.
When the drag starts, everything looks as expected: the dragged Image starts to move with the drag. But once it is moved a little bit (it seems, outside of its bounds), the original Image reappears and the dragged image (which now appears like a copy) twitches nastily and becomes smaller. When further dragging it around, it seems to somehow follow the 'depth' of the RealityView; when in the middle of the screen (on simulator), the image becomes smaller like due to perspective transform, and larger when near the sides of the screen.

Expected behaviour would be:

any hoverEffect on the drag source do not prevent the drag from starting. I suspect this is a bug in the platform and have actually filed a Feedback about it.
drag starts with no twitching, the dragged image follows the drag gesture all the way
the drag occurs in the plane of the attachment view or in any other 2D plane (perpendicular to the camera?)
the possible drop destination elements show a visual cue when dragging (at least when dragging onto them)
the possible drop destinations accept the drag and the DropDelegate methods get called

Tested this setup on Xcode 16 beta 4 / VisionOS 2.0 beta4 SDK simulator.
I guess my question boils down to the following: is it even possible (by design) to do drag and drop within attachments views of RealityView?
